# AWS data sync vs storage gateway use case

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-storage-gateway, aws-datasync

What is the real world use case difference between AWS data sync and storage gateway, since both allow data transfer from/to on premise data centre and AWS.

Comment: This is in fact a bit confusing as AWS docs say you can use DataSync for data transfer to and from S3 ... so that could also mean an integration solution just like what Storage Gateway promises !?? 

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/aws-datasync-hadoop-aws-storage-services/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One is for optimized data movement, and the other is more suitable for hybrid architecture.

AWS DataSync is ideal for online data transfers. You can use DataSync to migrate active data to AWS, transfer data to the cloud for analysis and processing, archive data to free up on-premises storage capacity, or replicate data to AWS for business continuity.

AWS Storage Gateway is a hybrid cloud storage service that gives you on-premises access to virtually unlimited cloud storage.

You can combine both services. Use AWS DataSync to migrate existing data to Amazon S3, and then use the File Gateway configuration of AWS Storage Gateway to retain access to the migrated data and ongoing updates from your on-premises file-based applications.